# checkboxlist select only one item

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to select only one checkbox from the list. Here is the code I am trying but it doesn't seem to be working.  I can use RadioButtonlist but it doesn't allow me to deselect the radio button. Please let me know.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var checkboxlistid = "#<%= chkLst.ClientID %>"; 
$(checkboxlistid + " input:checkbox").click(function () { 
 $(this).attr("checked",""); });
```

});

```
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkLst" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="U">Unknown</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="R">Ref</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: Your jQuery (JavaScript) runs in the browser, so against the HTML generated by your server. Posting the actual HTML rather than the server-side code would be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A checkbox is the wrong UI element for this task. Users expect certain behaviour out of radio buttons and checkboxes - don't mess with it. You're better off adding a CLEAR button than attempting to make checkboxes behave like radio buttons.

Answer (score 2):

That should not be a problem.. Basically when ever you select one item you need to clear all the checked items and then check the current item..

Try this code..

```
$(function() {
    $('[id*=chkLst] input[type="checkbox"]').on('click' , function(){
        // Caching all the checkboxes into a variable
        var checkboxes =  $('[id*=chkLst] input[type="checkbox"]');
        // If one item is checked.. Uncheck all and
        // check current item..
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            checkboxes.attr('checked', false);
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');        
        }
    });    
});​
```

Here is a working example..
 http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/hBSTC/2/